# Wilcoxon signed ranks test for reaction time

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I ran a within-subject study with the primary measure of interest being response time. Due to response time being right skewed I used Wilcoxon signed ranks test on the median values. I am having to revisit this work and I am now wondering/checking that using the Wilcoxon signed ranks test is feasible when working with response time.

The study was a within subject design with a single two level factor and the main measurement was reaction time. The total number of participants was 15

Comment: Why are you choosing the wilcox test? I understand that the response time measures are skewed but you are with a central tendency which is not skewed. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: My data is showing right skewed.  My understanding is that if I had more data then it would be normal based on the clt, however the data I have is right skewed as such I thought I had to either transform or use a non-parametric.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand your line of thought here. The samples you have are not normally distributed but the "population" would be normally distributed?

Comment: In this case you should always get more samples so that you have enough power in your test (whichever test you end up using)